# Difference between c-path, c'-path and indirect effect in mediation?

Tags: spss, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

I am currently doing a parallel multiple mediator analysis with **three mediators** (ECVOM, SOCFAC, SCMEAN) using the PROCESS macro in SPSS. My **DV** is HAPMEAN and my **IV** is CUSTOM.

I want to create a table that lists all the paths (a, b, c and c') for each mediator, as well as the respective indirect effect. However, I am having trouble distinguishing path c, path c' and the indirect effect in the SPSS output.

Is path c the total effect of CUSTOM on HAPMEAN, so .1266?
And my indirect effect for SCMEAN is .1522?

Is it correct that the output is not showing me path c' and I have to calculate it by hand (.1522 - .1266)?[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you wrote is correct. The total effect is of HAPMEAN on CUSTOM is .1266. The indirect effect of SCMEAN is .1522; and .0997 for SOCFAC.

The direct effect is there! The c’ prime is -.1324. It is the effect of CUSTOM on HAPMEAN with all other variables in the models.